# Must-Query with boosting in ScoutDriver Plus

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I want to do a boosting on a search. Fields are field_a, field_b. I have two different search-terms (search_term1 and search_term2). the search-terms are connected as two different sub-queries and i want to boost one of the subqueries higher than the other subquery. Something like this:

```
$subQuery1 = (new MatchQuery('field_a', 'search_term1'))->setBoost(1);
$subQuery2 = (new MatchQuery('field_b', 'search_term2'))->setBoost(5);

$boolQuery = (new BoolQuery())
    ->addMust($subQuery1)
    ->addMust($subQuery2);

$query = $query->setQuery($boolQuery);
```

But I can't find a way to to this in ScoutDriverPlus with laravel.